# Unable to get nested tables in efcore

Tags: c#, .net, ef-core-2.0

Hi I am working on efcore. I have table structure as below.

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string emailId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set;}
}

public class Project
{   
    public Project()
    {
        this.TimeSheetData = new HashSet<TimeSheetData>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("userId")]
    public virtual User User {get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TimeSheetData> TimeSheetData { get; set;}
}

public class TimeSheetData
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int project_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("project_id")]
    public virtual Project Project {get; set; }
    public string hours_logged { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get TimeSheetData like below.

```
public User GetTimeSheet(int userid)
        {
             return _context.Users.Include(u => u.Projects.Select(p => p.TimeSheetData)).Where(u => u.Id ==userid).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Which give me below error.

```
The Include property lambda expression 'u => {from Project p in u.Projects select [p].TimeSheetData}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'
```

I have used above namespaces in my file.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using TimeSheet.DataLayer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Can someone help me to figure out this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: in your dbcontext does `Project` table have a fk relation defined with `User`?

Comment: Yes I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is that you are using .Select() within .Include().  Include will use the navigation properties you defined in your classes to join your data together.

i think you should get your data using include, then use .Select() to choose what you want.  It would be something like

```
public User GetTimeSheet(int userid)
    {
         return _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id ==userid).Include(u => u.Projects).ThenInclude(t=> t.TimeSheetData).FirstOrDefault().Select(d=>d.TheDataYouWant);
    }
```

it may be less confusing to save the data to a variable, then return the pieces you want.  Chaining that many things together makes it easy to get lost in your own code

```
    public User GetTimeSheet(int userid)
        {
             var mydata =  _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id ==userid).Include(u => u.Projects).ThenInclude(t=> t.TimeSheetData).FirstOrDefault().Select(d=>d.TheDataYouWant);
             return mydata.myUser;
        }
```

Comment: hi Thanks for your answer. FirstOrDefault().select giving me compile error

Comment: Below code  var data = _context.Users.Include(u => u.Projects).ThenInclude(p => p.TimeSheetData).Where(a => a.Id == userid).ToList(); gives me all data but when returning User object will have only user and project data.

Comment: in my experience, using theninclude() returns nested items.  you may need to look at your project data and see if it has your timesheetdata class nested as a property